# Despite installing the torch vision pytorch library, I am getting an error saying that there is no module named torch vision

Tags: python, pytorch

The error that I am getting when I use `import torchvision` is this:

**Error Message**

```
"*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gokulsrin/Desktop/torch_basics/data.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torchvision
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision'*"
```

I don't know what to do. I have tried changing the version of python from the native one to the one downloaded through anaconda. I am using anaconda as a package manager and have installed torch vision through anaconda as well as through pip commands.

Comment: can you edit your post to reflect the *exact* commands you used to install `torchvision`? what is the output of `conda list torchvision`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From `PyTorch` installing [Docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) you should follow these steps:

- In **Anaconda** use this command:
  **`conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch`**
- In **Pip** use this command:
  **`pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`**

*Note:* If you have an enabled CUDA card you can change the `cpuonly` option to `cudatoolkit=10.1` or `cudatoolkit=9.2`

After successfully installing the package you can import it with the command *`import torchvision`* and the output should look like this:
[image]

Otherwise, there is something wrong when you are downloading the package from the Internet

Answer (score 6):

This command works

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

from https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#anaconda

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall jupyter notekook after pytorch installation worked for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that, despite making and building torchvision... there is an additional step to install it!

To build the [C++ API from source](https://github.com/pytorch/vision#c-api) (optional):

```
cd /location/to/vision
mkdir build && cd build
# Add -DWITH_CUDA=on to the below cmake command to build with support for CUDA
# Also add -DTorch_DIR=/path/to/Torch/ if necessary
cmake ..
make
make install
```

And then to [**install** torchvision from source](https://github.com/pytorch/vision#installation):

```
cd /location/to/vision
python setup.py install
```

This is assuming you clone torchvision to `/location/to/vision`:

```
cd /location/to
git clone https://github.com/pytorch/vision.git
```